# Number of solutions to $x_1x_2+x_3x_4 = 1$ (mod $n$)

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Show that the number of solutions $N$ to $x_1x_2+x_3x_4 = 1 \pmod n$ is

$$
N=n^2\phi(n)\prod_{p|n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{p} \right).
$$

Only thing I know how to start the problem is to consider:

$$
N = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_k^2 e(-\frac{k}{n}),
$$
where
$$
S_k=\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}e(\frac{kxy}{n}).
$$

But I have no idea what to do for a sum like this to conclude.

Comment: the right hand side is multiplicative but not completely multiplicative. if you can do this for primes and prime powers you have it.

Comment: @Michael That seems helpful, but I don't really know how to use that.

Comment: @WillJagy I dont think I can.. Tried to do it with primes but failed..

Comment: This is $n$ times the number of $(x_1,x_3)$ with $gcd(x_1,x_3,n)=1$.  So for prime powers, one of $x_1,x_3$ is a unit.  If $x_1$ is the unit, then there is one solution for all $n$ values of $x_4$.

Comment: @Michael https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function ?

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, show that the identity holds modulo $p$ for every $p$, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

In particular, modulo $p$, we can let $x_1,x_2$ take any values. A fraction $\frac{p^2-p+1}{p^2}$ of the time the quantity $1-x_1 x_2$ will be non-zero, and $\frac{p-1}{p^2}$ of the time it will equal $0$. In the first case, there are $p-1$ choices for $x_3$, and $1$ choice for $x_4$. In the second case there will be a total of $2p-1$ choices for $x_3$ and $x_4$ since we need only have $1$ of them equal to $0$. Thus the number of solutions modulo $p$ is $$p^2\left(\frac{p^2-p+1}{p^2}(p-1)+\frac{p-1}{p^2}(2p-1)\right)=p(p^2-1)=p^2\phi(p)\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$